# Handling NULL columns in rust-postgres

Tags: rust, nullable

I'm lost at something seemingly simple:

```
for row in &conn.query("SELECT r.id, r.name, l.name 
FROM rating r LEFT JOIN location l ON r.loc_id = l.id", &[]).unwrap() {
    let rating = Rating {
        id: row.get(0),
        name: row.get(1),
    };
}
```

This part works. What I can't get is the third column (`row.get(2)`).

Due to the `LEFT JOIN`, this row can have a `NULL` value. I've read the documentation, the related answers here and lots of Google pages and can't figure it out.

Obviously, I want to use `Option<>` somehow. And seemingly I want to use the `get_opt()` function.

In pseudo-code, what I want is this:

```
if row[2] is not null,
then $location = row[2]
else $location = null
```

Comment: Isn’t your pseudocode just `$location = row-2`?

Comment: https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/issues/96 -> `struct Rating { location: Option<String> }` & `Rating { location: row.get(2) }`.

Comment: @Shepmaster - yes, but the pseudo-code is just for illustration. what I'm actually doing is slightly more complex.

Comment: This question is NOT A DUPLICATE. I was aware of the linked question. Implementing the solution posted where into a struct assignment requires duplicate code that I'm sure can be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

I found something that works, though I'm not sure if it is the right solution:

```
let x: Option<f64> = row.get(1);
if let Some(_i) = x {
   // do something
}
```